# MacVim: White area on right side

Tags: vim, macvim

I recently switched from vim to MacVim. I noticed upon the first start, that there is a border at the right side of the MacVim Window: [image] (right side under "buffer").

Does anyone know how to remove this border?

Comment: What gives `set guioptions?`  command ?

Comment: It returns `gmrL`

Comment: Try with `set guioptions-=r` it could be the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks that worked! If you add your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove it by :

```
 set guioptions-=r
```